# Use LINQ and C# to make a new List from an old List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

This should be pretty simple, but I am new at LINQ. I have a `List<FillStruct>` of `FillList` structs. I'd like to use LINQ to create a new `List<NewFillStruct>` where instead of having the number of buys and sells, I would have one variable containing the sum.

For example, if the `FillStruct` structure has

```
buy = 4
```

and

```
sell = 2
```

then the `NewFillStruct` structure will have

```
numlong = 2.
```

If the `FillStruct` structure has

```
buy = 2
```

and

```
sell = 4
```

then the `NewFillStruct` structure will have

```
numlong = -2.
```

Here are the structures.

```
struct FillStruct 
{
    int buy;
    int sell;
    string date;
}

struct NewFillStruct
{
    int numlong;
    string date;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
List<FillStruct> origList = ...
List<NewFillStruct> newList = origList.Select(x => new NewFillStruct {
    numlong = x.buy - x.sell, date = x.date
}).ToList();
```

However, note that `struct` is not *necessarily* a good choice for this (prefer `class` unless you have a good reason).

Or to avoid LINQ entirely:

```
List<NewFillStruct> newList = origList.ConvertAll(x => new NewFillStruct {
    numlong = x.buy - x.sell, date = x.date
});
```

Comment: Great Answer, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This will select all your data from the enumerable "fillstructs" and create an enumerable of "NewFillStruct" containing the calculated values.

```
 var newfills = from fillstruct in fillstructs
               select new NewFillStruct
               {
                   numlong = fillstruct.buy - fillstruct.sell,
                   date = fillstruct.date
               };
```